# Open Excel links in other than default browser

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I have many hyperlinks to web pages in an Excel file and I want to open those links either in IE or Chrome depending on the link. Most of my links I use I have no issues with opening the default Chrome browser and that is fine but some I wish to open with IE. Is this possible to do with a hyperlink in the Excel file?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Native behavior for Excel is to use the system default browser. Therefore, it is not as simple as creating a hyperlink which opens a specific browser. What have you researched and attempted so far?

Comment: This may be useful: http://superuser.com/questions/384637/specific-browser-for-specific-links

Comment: You say "depending on the link". Do you mean the user should get to choose, or you'd like Excel to decide for itself based on some rules you give it? Either way it's going to be a VBA job.

Comment: misha256 - I am kinda new to VBA but it seems to me to be a possible solution to my problem. I have a pass protected Excel file that I keep site information in and I use hyperlinks so that when I need to go to that site I just click the hyperlink in the file. I mostly use Chrome but a couple of sites I need IE for, Chrome just doesn't display correctly or maybe I just don't know how to set the browser correctly. Either way, I want the hyperlink to open in the specified browser. I have no problem using VBA code for each file IF that will do what I want but as I said I am kinda new to VBA.

Comment: Yass - There was one solution on the link you provided that looks interesting but...that solution is to change the extension for the files that should open in a different browser. Question about that; would I have to create a different file extension for Each file to be opened in IE or would I just be able to use the same new file extension for all the URLs that I want to open with IE?

Comment: Note: I use my excel file to open links because I use multiple computers and don't want to put browser shortcuts on all of them. I have used VBA on a different Excel project but I really know Very little about VBA.