# Open Link in different Profile in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I'd like to have Firefox open Links in another Profile. Preferrably in way that I can set some URLs to open in the same Profile.

My use case:

I've set up a Firefox profile without navigation bar, which holds all my messenger web apps, which is started automatically on startup.

If someone sends me a link via messenger, it is opened in this profile though, which isn't practical without the navbar and in terms of workflow.
I'd like to have a setup, where all the internal messenger links(say https://web.telegram.org/*) are opened in the messenger profile and all external links are opened in my default Firefox profile.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do that too. I'll keep you posted if I find a solution. This solution works on Mac OS: https://superuser.com/q/316771/215736

Comment: I posted an answer which at least comes close to what i wanted on linux/firefox. There are probably similar plugins for different browsers, too.

Answer (score 4):

This is not really what I wanted so I won't mark this as the correct answer, but this is the closest I got with my setup so far:

I installed the [Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) Firefox add-on, which gives you the possibility to context-click-open a link with another Browser, or to have a toolbar icon to move the opened site to another browser.

In order to be able to select a specific profile with this plugin I made a copy of the firefox.dektop file (in /usr/share/applications on ubuntu 16.04) and changed the lines `Name=Firefox Web Browser` to `Name=Firefox Web Browser -default` and more importantly `Exec=firefox %u` to `Exec=firefox -P default %u`.

You can substitute "default" for whatever profile you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The official Firefox add-on for this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/ .
There is no setting page for adding URLs to different containers, but after open one in the container, you could select `Always open in XXX`(XXX is the container name, such as Personal, Banking, Shopping).

Here is the docs: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers

Or/and you may be interested in this question. [How can I always open certain URLs/domains in certain browsers?](https://superuser.com/questions/316771/how-can-i-always-open-certain-urls-domains-in-certain-browsers)

Comment: If I got the concept of firefox containers right, it's not what I'm looking for, as containers still live in the same firefox instance and only access a different part of memory.  
My use case is about opening in a different browser instance not because of privacy but because of different browser styling.  
The program recommended in the link won't work for me either as it is only available for OSX.