# Firefox profile priority for new links

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have two Firefox profiles, `default` and `work`

Is there a way to open new links in the `work` profile but only if that profile is active, ie. the window is open?

Something like this:

```
click link from outside Firefox
if `work` is active
  open link in `work` profile
else
  open link in `default` profile
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (I think), but check out [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/).

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1244035/open-link-in-different-profile-in-firefox

Comment: As a start, several ways to show a prompt and choose the browser and/or profile when you click a link are in the replies to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487203/choose-which-browser-to-open-link-in