# Can I have Firefox open all links in default browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, web-application

I'm using a tool called [Ice](https://github.com/peppermintos/ice) that creates special Firefox profiles for web apps (like Twitter or WhatsApp) to have them run in Firefox windows resembling Firefox' former site-specific browser feature.

Now when I click links in those web apps running in special Firefox profiles, they open as a new tab in the web app window (where the tabs are invisible) - so I would like to have all links open in my default browser (or the default profile of Firefox for that matter) instead.

There is an `about:config` option named `browser.link.open_newwindow` which supports the following values [according to mozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow):

- 1: Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in the current tab/window.
- 2: Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in a new window.
- 3: Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in a new tab in the current window.

Ideally, there would be an option to open those links using the system's default (like using xdg-open on Linux), which would open the link using my default browser / Firefox' default profile.

Is there some config item that I'm missing - or an add-on for Firefox that does just that (letting the system handle opening the link)? Does anyone have another idea?

Edit:@harrymc linked me this question (thanks!): [Open Link in different Profile in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1244035/open-link-in-different-profile-in-firefox) (they asked for pretty much the same thing, so my question is a duplicate).
The answer was to use an extension named [Open With](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) - and it's *almost* what I need! Now I can right-click any page or link to open it with another browser (or profile) - but it doesn't automatically open all links with that – Problem not fully solved.

Comment: Are these special browser windows running using Firefox or in some third-party browser?

Comment: yes, they're using firefox, but in a separate profile, launched using `firefox --profile /home/sk22/.local/share/ice/firefox/twitter --no-remote https://twitter.com`

Comment: @harrymc almost! it doesn't automatically open links in a different browser, but it at least allows me to manually do that. thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using Firefox containers instead? I'm not sure how complicated implementing this would be, but for example the Facebook Container does exactly this to isolate Facebook-related stuff.

Comment: yeah no, i need a custom userChrome.css :/ but thanks for the idea! @gronostaj